# Global variable gets modified by local variable?

Tags: python, list, variables, del

I'm on python 3.7.9.

-I need to copy some items from a list into another list.

-Then I need to do calculations on My new list *without* changing the original list.

But but whatever I do, my original list undergoes the same modifications that are done to my new list.

Could someone explain me Why ?

Thank's for your reply

**Debugging mode:**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are make the assignment:

```python
reduite = mat[1:]
```

This only *binds* `reduite` to the elements of `mat`.

In other words, the variable now references to the same objects in memory, which is why changing one will change the other (see also the reference on [Assignment statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements)).

Since `mat[1:]` is a list of lists, your best bet is probably to use `copy.deepcopy()` on assignment (see also the [documentation of `copy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy)).

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612815/15282257) also contains some great explanations of the various copy methods.

Answer (score 1):

This phenomenon is termed as shallow copy in python.

Basically,

```
 reduite=mat[1:]
```

is taking references of the inner objects(which are again arrays) of mat, hence modifying the copy array reflects on the original.

Use [deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) to solve this.